# Q: Material-Ui Appbar how to fix scrolling behind browser address bar

Tags: material-ui

I am using Material-Ui Appbar however when I scroll down the page the appbar goes underneath the address bar on iOS 10. And the address bar also stays open rather than collapsing. I am using the default material UI theme.

I dont assume it is supposed to work this way. Is there an example of how to do this correctly?

Ideally it would be great if the AppBar was fixed to the top of the page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually working as designed. If you want it to be fixed to the top of the page, you need to set CSS position to "fixed". This sticks the AppBar at the top, as desired, but since it is floating there it can obscure its own height's worth of content beneath it. So, you should compensate for that with some padding or margin (56px by default).  Example using padding on outer container:

```
<div style={{ paddingTop: 56 }}>
  <AppBar style={{ position: 'fixed', top: 0 }} />
  <p>
   Lots of tall/long content here...
  </p>
</div>
```

Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qe141fd2/1/

Comment: ok, but the AppBar height might be different, since it also adjusts to the content. Ist there a way that paddingTop gets its value from the actual height of the AppBare?